# How to get factor loadings in python with sklearn.decomposition FactorAnalysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am running a factor analysis on my stock returns matrix (200*676) using `sklearn.decomposition` FactorAnalysis. But I don't know how to get the factor loadings. This is how my code looks:

```
fa = FactorAnalysis(n_components=10, max_iter=30) 
fa.fit(stock_return_matrix)
```

Is the `fa.components_` factor loadings? If not, how to get the factor loadings?

Comment: I think you are looking for `fa.transform(stock_return_matrix)` which will give you the loading matrix. Check [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html)

Comment: Thank you, what are the difference between fit, fit_transform and transform?

Comment: In [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) the function `fit` is usually for learning a model from training examples and `transform` then applies that model for examples to get some new output. In case of [FactorAnalysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html), the output of `transform` is your examples in reduced dimension. `fit_transform` just combines the two functions, so it can make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The loading matrix is given in `fa.components_`.

`fa.transform()` doesn't give the loading matrix, but the estimated latent/hidden variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes fa.components_ is the loadings. However, if your study objective include interpretation of Factors, it is better to use a Factor Analysis package that allows rotation (eg:- factor_analyzer).